# Using Python to organize a data table into a dictionary of lists of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Looking for some help. I am trying to pull the text from a table and organize the data into a dictionary of lists of lists. 
The table is structured like this:

```
Date                Clock In    Clock Out   JobCode     Job
Monday     2/3/14   -           -                   -           -
Tuesday    2/4/14   16:00       17:30       5           Server
                    17:45       20:00       5           Server
Wednesday  2/5/14   -           -           -           -
Thursday   2/6/14   -           -           -           -
Friday     2/7/14   13:30       18:00       3           Cook
Saturday   2/8/14   -           -           -           -
Sunday     2/9/14   -           -           -           -
```

What I need is to return the data in this table structured like this:

```
MyDict = {"Monday 2/3/14":[[]],
      "Tuesday 2/4/14":[[16:00, 17:30, "5", "server"],
                        [17:45, 20:00, "5", "server"]],
      "Wednesday 2/5/14":[[]],
      "Thursady 2/6/14":[[]],
      "Friday 2/7/14":[[13:30, 18:00, 3, cook]],
      "Saturday 2/8/14":[[]],
      "Sunday 2/9/14":[[]]
      }
```

The individual timecards need to have their data organized into a list that are then further put into a list under the individual days.
I am going to take a snapshot of this data, generate a new timecard, and then take a new snapshot to compare to the old one to verify the new timecard is in the correct place with the correct data. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Nice. So have you tried anything yet? If so [edit] that and what went wrong with that approach in the question. If not, then try something first and the community will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It's great for handling any tabular data. Use the `read_csv` function to read it in.

You'll have some trouble as you don't have a clear separator (we can't use space as a separator as your dates and headers have a space). You may have to modify the input format a little to work with it (e.g. use comma as a separator).